# Why is Bibtex ordering references by citation, not alphabetically?

Tags: bibtex, natbib

My bibliography is sorted by citation order, not alphabetically and I don't understand why. I want it to be alphabetical and I think it *should* be in alphabetical order.

My preamble is,

```
\documentclass[iop, revtex4, twocolumn, appendixfloats, numberedappendix]{emulateapj}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\citestyle{apj}
\usepackage{natbib}
```

Then I insert my bibliography with,

```
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\bibliography{biblio}
```

I've used these packages and document classes previously and the bibliography was ordered alphabetically. Anyone have any idea what is going on and how I might go about fixing it?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Generally speaking, the order should be determined by `\bibliographystyle{apj}` and your file should produce whatever ordering `apj.bst` intends (I'm not sure if that is citation or alphabetical order).  Note that after changing something like `\bibliographystyle` it is necessary to run the full `latex bibtex latex latex` cycle to get references/bibliography as intended.

Comment: Off-topic: `subfigure` is obsolete and shouldn't be used. `hyperref` should be loaded last with certain exceptions, such as `cleveref`. `usenames` is deprecated, I think. Consider `xcolor` in place of `color`.

Answer (score 2):

The usual is sort by citation order when the cites are numbers (like "foo [1], bar [2], ...") and alphabetically when the style of the cite is author-year (like "Smith (1981)" or "(Smith, 1981)").  Using `natbib`  you should use the `authoryear`  option (i.e, `\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}` in your preamble) and a compatible style. For example, `plainnat` or `chicago` are both ok for this, `unsrt` obviously is not. Fortunately, `apj` seems to work well with the `authoryear` option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\begin{document}
... foo \citep{IEEEexample:article_typical}.\par
... baz \citep{IEEEexample:biblatex}.\par
... bar \citet{IEEEexample:conf_typical}.\par 
\bibliographystyle{apj}
\bibliography{IEEEexample}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]